# Using FloatRangeSlider widget in interactive mode

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

i just tried some features of ipywidgets lately by following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SN0Bflf14C4&t=937s&pbjreload=10. In the tutorial he shows how to use interact to interactively update a sine function graph.

I was just wondering if i can use FloatRangeSlider in interactive mode to dynamically change the x axis input range. Here is the script that i've tried to

```
amp = widgets.FloatSlider(min=1,max=10,value=1,description="Amp")
phase = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0,max=5,value=0,description="Phase")
freq = widgets.FloatSlider(min=1,max=10,value=0,description="Freq")
x = widgets.FloatRangeSlider(min=0,max=1)

f,ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(7,4))
ax.set_ylim([-10,10])
plt.suptitle("Sine Wave")

def update_plot(x,amp,phase,freq):

    ax.clear()
    y = amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*(freq*x+phase))
    ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.set_ylim([-10,10])
    ax.set_xlim([0,1])
    ax.grid()
    plt.show()

widgets.interactive(update_plot,x=x,amp=amp,phase=phase,freq=freq)
```

I want to control the range of the curve based on the floatrangeslider, but apparently the widget returns tuple, and i've tried to unpack the tuple and creating a linspace object in the range of `FloatRangeSlider.value[0]` to

`FloatRangeSlider.value[1]`, but error message appeared

```
def update_plot(x,amp,phase,freq):
---> 13     x1 = x.value[0]
     14     x2 = x.value[1]
     15     xt = np.linspace(x1,x2,50)
            ax.clear()
            y = amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*(freq*xt+phase))
            ax.plot(x,y)
            ax.set_ylim([-10,10])
            ax.set_xlim([0,1])
            ax.grid()
            plt.show()

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'
```

but i can still unpack the tuple from FloatRangeSlider when i tried it in different cell

```
x = widgets.FloatRangeSlider(min=0,max=1)
x1=(x.value[0])
x2=(x.value[1])
xt = np.linspace(x1,x2,100)
print(x1,x2,xt)

0.25 0.75 [0.25       0.25505051 ...0.75      ]
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: In your last code example, x is the widget object, but using the interactive function call passes the value of your widgets into the function. Hence `x` is passed as a tuple. So you are trying to call `.value` on a tuple, hence `AttributeError`.

Just use `x1, x2 = x` in your function body to unpack x into components.

Comment: It works, thank you very much!

Comment: @ac24 Can you submit this as an actual answer with a working solution for acceptance?